# Coherent states in QFT and Poisson distribution

Tags: quantum-field-theory, coherent-states

Consider a scalar field interacting with an external source $J(x)$ for a finite period of time. The vacua for before and after are defined by
$$ a_\mathbf{p} \left| 0_- \right> = 0$$
$$ A_\mathbf{p} \left| 0_+ \right> = \left(a_\mathbf{p} + \frac{i}{\sqrt{2 \omega_\mathbf{p}}}\tilde{J}(p) \right)\left| 0_+ \right>=0 $$
and therefore $\left| 0_+ \right>$ is a coherent state with respect to $a_\mathbf{p}$. I can easily show that
$$\left| 0_+ \right> = \mathcal{N} \exp{\left(-i\int\frac{d^3\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3 \sqrt{2 \omega_\mathbf{p}}}a_\mathbf{p}^\dagger \tilde{J}(p)\right)}\left| 0_- \right>,$$
where $$\mathcal{N}=\exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{d^3\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3 2 \omega_\mathbf{p}} \left| \tilde{J}(p) \right|^2\right)}.$$
Furthermore, I can easily show that the probability of finding vacuum w.r.t. $A_\mathbf{p}$ is $$P(0)=\left| \left< 0_+ \middle| 0_- \right>\right|^2=e^{-\lambda},$$ where $$\lambda =\int\frac{d^3\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^32 \omega_\mathbf{p}} \left| \tilde{J}(p) \right|^2. $$
Now, **here's what driving me crazy**...
I know that the probability for finding $n$ particles should obey the *Poisson distribution*, i.e. $$P(n)=\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda}$$ and I know I've derived it at least several times aeons ago, but I simply can't get it to work now. Here's my calculation (induction), help me out, I must be missing something obvious...
$$P(n+1) = \left| \left< (n+1)_+ \middle| 0_- \right>\right|^2 = \left| \left< n_+ \middle| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\int\frac{d^3\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3} A_\mathbf{p} \middle| 0_- \right>\right|^2 = \left| \left< n_+ \middle| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\int\frac{d^3\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3} \left(a_\mathbf{p} + \frac{i}{\sqrt{2 \omega_\mathbf{p}}}\tilde{J}(p) \right) \middle| 0_- \right>\right|^2 = \left| \left< n_+ \middle| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\int\frac{d^3\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3} \left( \frac{i}{\sqrt{2 \omega_\mathbf{p}}}\tilde{J}(p) \right) \middle| 0_- \right>\right|^2 = \frac{1}{n+1} \left| \int\frac{d^3\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2 \omega_\mathbf{p}}} \tilde{J}(p) \right|^2 P(n)$$

This would be true **if** $$ \left| \int\frac{d^3\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2 \omega_\mathbf{p}}} \tilde{J}(p) \right|^2 = \int\frac{d^3\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^32 \omega_\mathbf{p}} \left| \tilde{J}(p) \right|^2$$ which **isn't true** in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the integral $\int \frac{d^3\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3}$ inside the $|\cdot|^2$ you would be computing the overlap between $|0_-\rangle$ and the specific linear combination given by the integral over the momenta of $A_{\mathbf{p}}|n_+\rangle$, whereas if you put the integral outside you sum the probabilities of overlapping $|0_-\rangle$ with any state $A_{\mathbf{p}}|n_+\rangle$ for any momentum.

The latter is what you want to do and if I'm not mistaken you would obtain the correct formula.

---

As a side note, the integral inequality
$$ \left| \int\frac{d^3\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2 \omega_\mathbf{p}}} \tilde{J}(p) \right|^2 \leq \int\frac{d^3\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^32 \omega_\mathbf{p}} \left| \tilde{J}(p) \right|^2\,,$$
is consistent with the fact that the probability of overlapping with a specific linear combination is less than the probability of overlapping with *any* linear combination.

Comment: Ah, yes... a silly mistake in sloppy probabilistic reasoning, of course! Thank you :)